# Safe UI update from Handler

Tags: java, android

I found sample code that contains UI usage not from main thread in `Head First Android Development` book.

According to my understanding content of `run(){}` runs in separate thread. And line `distanceView.setText(distanceStr);` is trying to use UI which is not allowed not from main thread. I am mistaken?

```
private void displayDistance()
    {
        final TextView distanceView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                double distance = 0.0;
                if (bound && odometer != null) {
                    distance = odometer.getDistance();
                }
                String distanceStr = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%1$,.2f miles", distance);
                distanceView.setText(distanceStr);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Handler() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler()):

> Default constructor associates this handler with the `Looper` for the current thread.

Therefore as long as `displayDistance()` is being called on the main thread, the *Handler* will use the main thread when running any `Runnable` passed to it.